# hot to get Google Calendar API event time zone right

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I'm writing a python code that add events on my google calendar, but when i input lets say 1 PM, it add the event at 5PM in the calendar.

The timeZone are well set up I think :

`'timeZone': 'America/New_York'`
`'timeZone': 'America/New_York'`

And my google calendar timezone setting is `GMT+00:00`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you want to serve it in your local time set google calendar timezone setting to GMT-04:00 for New York

Comment: thank you @Hisham___Pak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Hisham__Pak said, the Calendar Settings need to be at the correct Time Zone. Go to `Settings > Time zone` and change `Primary Time zone`:

[image]